# Поставил postgresql не получается зайти с pgadmin

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Поставил postgresql не получается зайти с pgadmin. При попытке зарегистрировать новый сервер выдает ошибку: "Error connecting to the server: не удалось подключиться к серверу: В соединении отказано. Он действительно работает по адресу "localhost" (127.0.0.1) и принимает TCP-соединения (порт 5432)?"

Comment: Скорее всего он не запущен

Comment: вроде запущен: https://hsto.org/files/f13/fd0/8aa/f13fd08aa8bd47f88d68e8dd792062c8.jpg

Comment: Может локалхост не прописан в конфиге или порт другой?

Comment: и это все вроде прописал: https://hsto.org/files/55d/9b0/278/55d9b027803a4bca88803aa2529e2f27.PNG